# rails4 putting search engine in main page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

Following railcasts tutorial on ransack, I was able to create search engine on my Post page. However, I want to implement those same search engine on my Welcome#index (main) page. I have tried in the same way, but whenever I click search, it returns to the welcome#index page instead of searched post page :( I am new to ruby on rails:(

This is my post controller:

```
 class PostsController < ApplicationController
     before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :vote]
     skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy, :vote]
 # GET /posts
 # GET /posts.json
    def index
      @search = Post.search(params[:q])
      @posts = @search.result
      @posts = @search.result(:distinct => true)
      @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?

     respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json{ render json: @posts}
     end
   end

 private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:area, :price, :people, :size, :description, :image)
  end
 end
```

posts index.html.erb:

```
<%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
  <h1>Search</h1>
    <%= f.label :area_cont, "area" %>
    <%= f.text_field :area_cont, class: "area_search"%>
  </div>

  <div class="post_actions">
   <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-warning" %>
   <%= link_to "Clear Search", request.path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  </div>

 <% end %>
```

welcome#index

```
        <p>
            <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
                <%= search_form_for @search do |f| %>
                  <div class="field">
                  <h1>Search</h1>
                    <%= f.label :area_cont, "area" %>
                    <%= f.text_field :area_cont, class: "area_search"%>
                  </div>

                  <div class="post_actions">
                  <%= f.submit %>
                  <%= link_to "Clear Search", request.path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
            </form>
        </p>
```

Welcome controller

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @search = Post.search(params[:q])
   @posts = @search.result
   @posts = @search.result(:distinct => true)
   @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?

   respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json{ render json: @posts}
  end
end
end
```

I just uploaded parts that would be relevant to this question :( please let me know if other part of code is necessary!! Thank you!

This is my welcome#index.html.erb:
and I have erased contents in welcome controller

```
<div id="headerwrap">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row centered">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
            <h1>search</b></h1>
            <p>
                <form class="navbar-search pull-left">
                    <%= form_tag("/posts", method: "GET") do %>
                    <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
                    <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
                    <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
                    <% end %>
                 </form>
            </p>
           </div>
          </div><!-- row -->
      </div><!-- container -->
     </div><!-- headerwrap -->
```

After running bundle exec

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your PostsController code.
You can try this.

The form in your welcome#index.html.erb, should have contained q param
For example,

```
<%= form_tag(search_posts_path, method: "GET") do %>
  <%= label_tag(:q, "Search for:") %>
  <%= text_field_tag(:q) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

And your Welcome Controller index action, can be empty. Because the form search through post controller index action.

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
 end
end
```

There are other ways to handle this like making a posts controller index to be a root (or you would call a main page) then invoke search method when there is a search param, pass the q param to welcome index action then redirect the param to post action etc.

Comment: this still returns to the welcome page when I press search :(

Comment: I just have updated welcome#index.html.erb on my original post!

Comment: Can you try to run `bundle exec rake routes` to see available routes ?

Comment: Ok, you map posts#index to "/posts/search". I updated the code. Basically you can use form_tag(search_posts_path, method: "GET") or form_tag("/posts/search", method: "GET")

Comment: That still doesn't route to post search :((

Comment: It's also good if you can paste the application log after you submit search.

Answer (score 0):

`welcome#index` keeps rendering for you, because you never tell Rrails not to do that when there is a search result.

So the `WelcomeController` snippet you shared should look like this:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @search = Post.search(params[:q])
   @posts = @search.result
   @posts = @search.result(:distinct => true)
   @search.build_sort if @search.sorts.empty?

   if @posts.count > 0
     # If we have any matches, render the posts/index view.
     render 'posts/index'
   else
    respond_to do |format|
     format.html 
     format.json{ render json: @posts}
    end
   end
 end
end
```

This is still a partial solution, because you have to take care of the case when the user enters a search string but there is no result, but this will get you started.